# java android Eclipse retrofit 2.0 Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lretrofit2/Converter

Tags: java, android

I want to use in project retorfit 2.0 when I build apk in logs I see :

```
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lretrofit2/Converter
```

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies are clashing -- more than one are trying to include the same thing. Try opening up a terminal and running the gradle `dependencies` task against your app. It will look something like `./gradlew app:dependencies`. The output will be your dependency tree. If you're on linux you may want to pipe the result to `grep` and limit the output to what you care about.

That command is `./gradlew app:dependencies | grep 'retrofit'`

Examine this output and look for elements higher up in the tree including, at lower levels, dependencies that are included already by other elements. When you find the rogue-includer head to your build file where you declare the dependency ie `implementation "com.retrofitincluder.thing:rogue:0.0.0"` and change it to:

`implementation ("com.retrofitincluder.thing:rogue:0.0.0") {
   exclude group: 'com.retrofit2.and so on', module: 'retrofit'
}`

You'll have to figure out the particular dependency and module names on your own but this is the basic process for resolving dependency collisions. Also note you can use `exclude module: 'justthemodule'` as well.